# Is adding too many people/characters to a story bad?

Tags: characters, world-building, story

im building a world for a screenplay and i would like to have some main characters I have already made some character profiles for some of them but i was wondering whether or not if adding too many characters will make the storyline confusing. I want to make 6 main characters, 24 secondary characters and 70 tertiary characters that wouldn't have large speaking roles. they would show up in an "episode" or "chapter" but that's it.

thxx

-brie